# How to create a File object in OPC UA server in C#?

Tags: c#, file, opc-ua, opc

I'm trying to create a File object so that the client can send a file through the server, but when I try to write a local file to the object it returns a [BadImplementation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOnfG.png).

Also, some attributes of the File object appear as invalid and take on the value [BadAttributeIdInvalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv0G9.png) and I don't know why.

I create a FileState node in the Files folder, as you can see below. And the [node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxuBW.png) appears on the client side as expected. But it doesn't work as mentioned before.

```
folder = opcServer_.CreateFolderState(root, "Files", "Files", "String");

FileState file = new(folder)
{
    SymbolicName = "FileName",
    Description = "File object",
    ReferenceTypeId = ReferenceTypes.Organizes,
    TypeDefinitionId = ObjectTypeIds.FileType,
    NodeId = ObjectIds.FileDirectoryType_FileName_Placeholder,
    BrowseName = new QualifiedName("FileName", NamespaceIndex),
    DisplayName = "FileName",
    RolePermissions = new(),
    UserRolePermissions = new(),
};

folder.AddChild(file);
opcServer_.AddNode(folder);
```

Does anyone know what else I need to implement to make this object work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

In OPC UA, file objects are created - if the server supports it (which is not always the case) - through the CreateFile method that you need to call. See https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/Core/docs/Part5/C.3.4 .

Comment: Do you know how I can confirm whether or not the server supports the File object? I tried using the CreateFile method of the FileDirectoryType object, but it still gives the BadImplementation error.

Comment: The error is BadNotImplemented. It tells you that CreateFile, at least on that node, is not implemented. The server may support many other things around FileDirectoryType, but those are not necessary related.